# Winforms with OpenId Connect

Tags: azure, winforms, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am working on Winforms (.NET Framework 4.6) and connecting to a .NET 6 API. I want to use OIDC for my Winforms and API, but I have a few questions on how to achieve this.

In the existing app, there is no API, user will be login to their machines with their LDAP credentials. There is no specific login process when using Winforms app. User will just click app and use it. When user performs CRUD operations, we are checking LDAP for permissions of user and proceed further based on permissions.

Now we are introducing the API with OIDC and OAuth 2.0 using Azure Active Directory.

We cannot introduce login form. Which flow should I use? And how do I get an access token with only user id as there is no login process?

Comment: Hi Raja, you can consider using the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow.

Comment: Client credentials means it is for app not for specific user. If I want to check permissions of user when accessing api how can I do it.

Comment: in this case give a try with the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow with PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) in your WinForms application.

Comment: ok. just using ldap user id and I can get code and access token with the code from azure active directory. Is my understanding right?

Comment: you are correct but there is something off, let me put it in the answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow with PKCEin your WinForms app.

Regarding the question: yes you are correct in understanding but there is a little details I want to add. In the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE, the code is obtained by the client application (your WinForms app) after the user authenticates through the Azure AD login page. The user's LDAP credentials are used during this authentication process. Let me show you a code snippet and explain a little better.

Use the MSAL.NET library to integrate auth in your WinForms app and implement the auth code flow with PKC

```
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
    .Build();

var result = await cca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
    .WithPkce()
    .ExecuteAsync();

var accessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

In your API, validate the received access token to ensure it's issued by Azure AD. Use the user's claims in the access token to check permissions:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
        options.Audience = "{clientId}";
    });

// Access user claims in your API controllers
[Authorize]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        // Check permissions based on the userId
        // Your logic here
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will implement this process and get back if any issues. Thanks for quick response

Comment: sure raja you can.

Comment: var result = await cca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
    .WithPkce()
    .ExecuteAsync(); 
does Prompt.SelectAccount will pop a browser and user has to perform action to get token. Can we do silent authentication and get the access token

Comment: Yes you can but when you use silent authentication, make sure to handle cases where silent authentication might not be possible.